# Deploy Ruby on Rails project on Heroku failed - You have deleted from the Gemfile: * pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I want to deploy my rails project to Heroku, but I occurred this error(build log details are at below), then I have tried several solutions like:

```
bundle update
git add .
git push "Gemfile.lock"
git push heroku master
```

```
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/ .bundle/ Gemfile.lock
bundle install
git push heroku master
```

And also tried the official suggestion in:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#bundler-2-2-3
But still can't be resolved.

Although the above solutions can resolve somebody's error but didn't fit my issue. I have been searching for a while still didn't figure out the reason.

Below are some information that may make this question more complete:

**System Information**

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Rails: Rails 6.1.4
Ruby: ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]
Bundle: Bundler version 2.2.19
```

**Heroku build log**

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.2.21
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.0.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.21
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       
       If this is a development machine, remove the /tmp/build_130d307f/Gemfile freeze 
       by running ``.
      
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * pg
       Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       If this is a development machine, remove the /tmp/build_130d307f/Gemfile freeze 
       by running ``.

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * pg
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.1'

gem 'rexml', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.4'
gem 'travis', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.10'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3', '>= 6.1.3.2'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails-i18n'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
    activerecord (6.1.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
    activestorage (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    backports (3.21.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.7.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.35.3)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    connection_pool (2.2.5)
    crass (1.0.6)
    diff-lcs (1.4.4)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    ethon (0.14.0)
      ffi (>= 1.15.0)
    faraday (0.17.4)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faraday_middleware (0.14.0)
      faraday (>= 0.7.4, < 1.0)
    ffi (1.15.3)
    gh (0.14.0)
      addressable
      backports
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      net-http-persistent (>= 2.7)
      net-http-pipeline
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    highline (1.7.10)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    json (2.5.1)
    launchy (2.5.0)
      addressable (~> 2.7)
    listen (3.5.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.10.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.1)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.0)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multipart-post (2.1.1)
    net-http-persistent (4.0.1)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2)
    net-http-pipeline (1.0.1)
    nio4r (2.5.7)
    nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    pg (1.2.3)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    pusher-client (0.6.2)
      json
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-mini-profiler (2.3.2)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-proxy (0.7.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.4)
      actioncable (= 6.1.4)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      actiontext (= 6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails-i18n (6.0.0)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      railties (>= 6.0.0, < 7)
    railties (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.13)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.1.1)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rspec-core (3.10.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.10.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.10.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-rails (4.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      railties (>= 4.2)
      rspec-core (~> 3.10)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.10)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.10)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10)
    rspec-support (3.10.2)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    spring (2.1.1)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.2)
    thor (1.1.0)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    travis (1.8.13)
      backports
      faraday (~> 0.9)
      faraday_middleware (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.1)
      gh (~> 0.13)
      highline (~> 1.6)
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      pusher-client (~> 0.4)
      typhoeus (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.8)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    typhoeus (0.8.0)
      ethon (>= 0.8.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (5.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket (1.2.9)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.4)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 3.26)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  listen (~> 3.3)
  pg
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rack-mini-profiler (~> 2.0)
  rails (~> 6.1.3, >= 6.1.3.2)
  rails-i18n
  rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.4)
  rspec-rails (~> 4.0.2)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  sqlite3 (~> 1.4)
  travis (~> 1.8, >= 1.8.10)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 4.1.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 5.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.0.1p64

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.19
```

Already have the Gemfile.lock but still fail to push on Heroku.
["Screenshot" have Gemfile.lock but still fail to push on Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ3Hr.jpg)

Comment: The error message says: *"Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the updated Gemfile.lock to version control."* ... So why did you **DELETE** the `Gemfile.lock` from version control?! The error message is telling you to do the exact opposite.

Comment: The whole point of `Gemfile.lock` is to record exactly what version of all dependencies your application is known to work with. Even if `heroku` allows it, I'd very strongly advise not to remove `Gemfile.lock` from source control -- it means your production application could deploy a broken build at any moment, without being caught by any form of QA/testing.

Comment: @TomLord I already tried the `bundle install` and `bundle update` before I try to delete the `Gemfile.lock`. I'm a beginner both of Ruby on Rails and Heroku, so I found some solution on either the StackOverflow or else forum then just give it a try, but it all didn't work well so I post this question here. Now I know I shouldn't delete the `Gemfile.lock`, does it have any remedial action to solve?

Comment: `Gemfile.lock` is a record of exact versions of all dependencies for the project. If you delete the file, then another system (e.g. `heroku`!) doesn't know which versions you were using - and the best it could do it try installing the latest versions of everything. So for example, suppose you're using `some-awesome-gem v1.0.0`, checked that it's working fine, clicked "deploy", but then... Oh dear, `some-awesome-gem v2.0.0` has now been released! And since `heroku` had no idea you were using version 1, it would automatically fetch version 2.

Comment: Every time you run `bundle install` or `bundle update`, the `Gemfile.lock` will be (re)created if it doesn't exist already. Then in future, `bundle install` will **NOT** edit the file, whereas `bundle update` *might* edit the file ... If it finds anything that can be updated! So to answer yout question, the "remedial action" is... Run `bundle install; git add Gemfile.lock; git commit -m "Don't delete the Gemfile.lock from source control"`

Comment: I have been try `bundle install` before and also have `Gemfile.lock` already, now I try again it doesn't change and shows `nothing to commit, working tree clean`. `Run 'bundle install' elsewhere and add the updated Gemfile.lock to version control` I have been tried but didn't make any difference. Since I didn't know where is `elsewhere`, so I just run the command at my project directory. Also, I try to `remove the /tmp/build_130d307f/Gemfile` as the error message was shown but didn't have that directory or file.

Comment: @TomLord And after I try the step that error message suggest, but everything still keep the same...

Comment: What does this comment mean" *"now I try again it doesn't change and shows nothing to commit, working tree clean"* I don't know what "it" is, that you tried. Re-reading your previous comments, your `git` commands don't really make sense.

Comment: These are the basic step for pushing everything to master: (1) `git checkout master`. (2) `bundle install`. (3) `git add .` (4) `git commit -m "Message goes here"` (!!!!) (5) `git push heroku master`.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to `git push "Gemfile.lock"`, as you stated previously. And trying to `push` before you have `commit`ted won't do anything.

Comment: As for the`/tmp/build_130d307f/Gemfile` you tried to delete, this is a file **ON HEROKU**, not on your local machine.  If you want to delete that file, you need to SSH onto the heroku server.

Comment: Sorry about my describe not clear enough, my comment is mean that I'm already try the commit and push before to update my repository on github, but `git push heroku master` still didn't work.

Comment: So to be absolutely clear, you are saying: You have committed and pushed the `Gemfile.lock` to heroku, and yet the heroku error message still says that `Gemfile.lock` has not been added???

Comment: Yes exactly. Both my repository and local have `Gemfile.lock`, but when I try to `git push heroku master` then get the error say not been added.